# Two structs that access eachother in cpp

Tags: c++, struct

I have two structs that access each other. I forward declared them but there is still a compiler error.

> 'Node' was not declared in this scope and 'Node' does not name a type.

```
struct Node;
struct Edge;

struct Node
{
    unsigned intersectionID;
    bool visited;
    std::vector <Edge*> leavingedges;
};

struct Edge
{
    unsigned streetsegmentID;
    double weight;
    Node* endingnode;
};
```

Comment: And what is the error you get?

Comment: Well, what does the error say?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/psDXZe Please provide a full [mcve] that reproduces the error

Comment: @UnholySheep Uh, that's because you fixed the problem in what you put in the godbolt. If you just straight copy-paste the OP's code, then you get the error.

Comment: @JosephSible according to OP the error they get is that `Node` was not declared, which is not the error you get when removing `#include <vector>`

Comment: @UnholySheep Oh. I missed that they edited that in since my answer.

Comment: In any case the code they posted is clearly not the same as the code that they're compiling to get that error.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `#include <vector>`. When I add that, your code compiles fine.